# ASP.NET, PostgreSQL, Mono, Ubuntu, Apache: Good idea?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, asp.net, postgresql, mono

I am a long-time Microsoft .NET developer. ASP.NET/MSSQL/IIS has been my bread & butter over the past 6 years.

Now, I'm getting fond of the "lightweightness" of Ubuntu 10.xx server. I'm also loving SSH-ing it from my Windows 7 PC and installing apps using the awesome "apt-get" command.

I've also been using HeidiSQL with MySQL now and loving it. It feels like Management Studio. However, i've read that PostgreSQL "may" be better than MySQL, and I did experience some MySQL overloads in my Moodle box (but this can be just a poor tweaking in my part).

My question is, would it be a good idea to run this configuration?

ASP.NET 4.0
PostgreSQL (the latest one I can apt-get!)
Ubuntu 10.10 with Mono running on Apache

Also, I assume I would be using Npgsql for Mono as my connector from ASP.NET to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, would it be a good idea to run this configuration?

I personally use MySQL as a database system for ASP.NET MVC based applications running on Mono, but I guess PostgreSQL is fine too. My experience is that MySQL has a better support for various tools (for example Workbench) and writing stored procedures is much more simpler (take it as subjective experience).

> Also, I assume I would be using Npgsql for Mono as my connector from ASP.NET to PostgreSQL?

Exactly.

Comment: "writing stored procedures is much more simpler": Sure, but stored procedures are very limited in MySQL in comparison with PostgreSQL...

Comment: well, coming from MS SQL Server, I think MySQL and PostgreSQL Stored Procs are not so exciting hehe. One reason i'm moving to Linux to host my .NET is nowadays, I mostly use a bunch of ASP.NET SQLDataSource control where I put my queries, and I like the portability of being able to edit the .aspx files in a simple text editor.